# segmentation fault on resizing a vector of large structures

Tags: c++, vector, struct, segmentation-fault

The code below is generating a segementation fault, and I do not understand why. The code below uses a vector to store multiple large strucutres, but the code does not run and generates a segmentation fault. I don't understand why. My understanding is that vector resize allocates memory in heap so this shouldn't be a stack overflow problem. My system has very large physical memory (256 GB) and the code is compiled in 64 bit mode so allocating just 40 MB should not be a problem. Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance,

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct _tmp_t {
    int a_data[10*1000*1000];/* large array */
} tmp_t;

int main( void ) {
    vector<tmp_t> v_tmp;

    v_tmp.resize( 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's all there is for code? `resize` could potentially need twice as much memory as the current `capacity`, but shouldn't be a problem for this particular case. Where does the segfault point to?

Comment: In C++, for at least 15 years now, you don't need to typedef your structs.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that calling `std::vector::resize` will create temporary objects (note that it has a second argument that defaults to `T()`); these reside on the stack.  So you're blowing your stack.

Comment: That makes sense, but is there really a reason that stl vector should create a temporary object for just resizing?

Comment: @Kang: Yes.  It needs to construct each new object; `resize` copy-constructs based on its second argument.  If you don't provide a second argument, then it uses the default, which is `T()`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `c++0x` should "fix" this, as the new allocator model will allow in-place default constructing of objects when something like `::resize` is called without an object to copy from. In `c++03` you could create a temporary object on the heap and pass that to `::resize` to copy from...

Comment: @Darren, I don't think that creating the temp on the heap will help. The object is passed by value, so it will consume stack space either way.

Comment: @Rob - yeah that's true - I'd assumed it was `T const& = T()` - but it's just by value as you say.

Comment: it would help if the vector could be switched out to a vector<tmp_t*> but that brings its own problems