# Why does std::vector::resize(n, src) pass by value?

Tags: c++

Pretty much as per the title.

The spec for `std::vector<T>::resize` seems to require that the `src` object be passed by value:

```
void resize(size_type n, T src = T() );
```

Why isn't a reference to a constant object used here instead?

```
void resize(size_type n, T const& src = T() );
```

For instance, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438968/segmentation-fault-on-resizing-a-vector-of-large-structures), the pass-by-value aspect appears to cause stackoverflow issues, due to the creation of a temporary object on the stack.

If a reference to `src` was passed instead, we'd at least be able to workaround the issue by allocating a temporary on the heap which is passed-by-reference to `::resize()`.

It also seems that `::resize()` is out of step with the other member functions for `std::vector`. For instance, the constructors take a `src` object by `const&` as expected:

```
vector (size_type n, T const& src = T(), Allocator const& = Allocator() );
```

EDIT: I dug out the `c++03` standard and double checked that the function prototypes above are not mis-quoted...

Comment: Isn't a default value for a const-reference something new that was only introduced in C++11?

Comment: @Kerrek Last time I checked, it worked in C++03. Then again, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Kerrek - just had a squiz through the `2003` standard, the `T const& = T()` pattern seems to be in there...

Comment: @Kerrek, if the spec for the vector constructor is correct then it *must* have been allowed. The only question is if the spec given is from the standard or from some other incorrect source.

Comment: Yeah, that was just my mistake then. No idea... good question, though! Interestingly, the underlying allocator *does* take the prototype by const-reference rather than by copy.

Comment: @Mark Ransom - I double checked with `c++03`!

Comment: @Darren, thanks - I hadn't seen your comment before I posted mine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was [a mistake in the Standard Library specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#679).  It is fixed in C++11; `std::vector` now has two `resize` member functions declared as:

```
void resize(size_type sz);
void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
```

The difference between the two is that if the size of the container is larger after the resize, the first overload value initializes the new elements, while the second copy constructs them; this pattern is used for other member functions and in other containers too.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: The benefit of hindsight :) The only question is why such simple changes took so long...

Comment: @Matthieu - I like that the defect report indicates it was known and debated pre-`c++98`...

Comment: Yes, and it's news to me that `push_back(v[0])` must work. So C++11 resize has to: 1) allocate a new internal buffer, 2) copy-construct the new elements, 3) move the old elements, 4) destruct elements and free the old buffer. Right? It can't do 3 before 2, and neither can `push_back`.

Comment: @Darren: The DR says "before C++98 was _ratified_". That leaves open the possibility that C++98 was already in FDIS - Final Draft.

Comment: @Steve - for sure you can self-assign, via `push_back(v[0])` or `resize(n, v[0])` etc. I think that the process would be: 1) check for self-assignment, if so find the *index* within the current vector storage we're assiging from (since the index is invariant after a realloc), 2) realloc a new buffer, 3) copy-ctor new elements (from `v[index]` if self-assigning), 4) move old elements, 5) destruct and free old buffer. Both `push_back` and `resize` should work along similar lines here - my `msvc 2010` does something like this already...